# JSON API data from Array to table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, api

I'm a bit stuck trying to retrieve and display the correct information inside of a table, based on data obtained from an API and symbols which are stored in the database. In short, when I do this:

```
$div = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$z&types=stats&filter=dividendRate");  
$div = json_decode($div,TRUE);  
foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
echo '<br/>'. $divi.' : '. $value['stats']['dividendRate'];
}
```

I get the correct outcome, which is this:
FB : 0
GOOGL : 0
AAPL : 2.52

But this only shows it in a simple list, whereas if I want to display this in a table, I can only get it to show the correct symbols but the value for all is 2.52, no matter what. Code:

```
            <td>
                <?php 
                echo '<br/>'. $symbol[$x].' : '. $value['stats']['dividendRate']; 
                ?> 
            </td>
```

Is it to do with the way I'm referencing this or something? If any additional code from the program is needed then let me know because this is obviously only a part of it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try
echo '<br/>'. $symbol[$x].' : '. $divi['stats']['dividendRate'];

Comment: What is `$z` ? Could you give an example value?

Comment: Farhan, I tried all combinations of the variables there and I get a different kind of error every time. When I try the solution u mentioned, I get the correct symbol still but then "Warning: Illegal string offset 'stats'" & "Warning: Illegal string offset 'dividendRate'" so not sure if that helps at all? As for $z Phil, it's the variable that is used to store the symbols that are in the db. So e.g. AAPL is an example of $z. Hope that helps. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this solved the issue:

```
foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
                echo $value['stats']['dividendRate']; 
                }
```